# How to build a bones animation engine?

Tags: flash, physics, actionscript-3, physics-engine

I want to develop a flash game. It would draw a stick man, and edit his pose.

I think what I need to learn are **bones animation** and **physics engine**.

Can anyone introduce some good resources to learn both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120428021220/http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Basic_Bones_System) is another such tutorial, which might help you.

It's very thorough, and I even used it once to produce an animation engine. The theory is very good and it should be easily understood for you to use it in AS3.

Answer (score 4):

I'd look into a physics engine like [Box2D](http://www.box2dflash.org/) or [Nape](http://code.google.com/p/nape/). These engines come with several different joints you can use to animate lots of different stuff. Here's an [example of the different joints/constraints](http://www.newgrounds.com/dump/item/9a2d2f8c69ad6af45e6535c2c1e2f320) possible.

On the Box2D (for Flash) homepage you'll also find a Ragdoll example which probably comes really close to what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you could take the [ragdoll-example code](http://box2dflash.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/box2dflash/Examples/TestBed/TestRagdoll.as?revision=158&view=markup) as a starting point for your own modifications?

Comment: +1 for attempting to use existing libraries instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Ragdoll physics are great for ragdolls.  Not so great for posing/animation.  Ideally the ragdoll will closely resemble the rig, but they are not driven by the same system.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [skeleton animation tutorial](http://www.rookscape.com/vbgaming/tutBD.php) over at Rookscape. It's VB based  but the theory should be sound. Also take a look at some of the [other tutorials](http://www.rookscape.com/vbgaming/tutorials.php) if need be...

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely take a look at some of the underlying principals in skeletal movements.

General background: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics

Good pictures here: http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_ik.htm

This guy was doing 2D stick figures: http://www.chrishecker.com/Inverse_Kinematics